# Iterating over a NameValueMap in Autodesk Inventor

Tags: c#, autodesk-inventor

I tried iterating over a NameValueMap using a 0-based index but it did not work. Iterating over it using a 1-based index worked.

Did not work.

```
public static void onParameterChange(_Document document,
                                     Inventor.Parameter parameter,
                                     EventTimingEnum BeforeOrAfter,
                                     NameValueMap context ,
                                     out HandlingCodeEnum handlingCode)
{
   handlingCode = HandlingCodeEnum.kEventHandled;

   // Did not work. Got an exception.
   for ( int i = 0; i < context.Count; ++i )
   {
      string name = context.Name[i];
      string value = (string)context.Value[name];
   }
}
```

Worked.

```
public static void onParameterChange(_Document document,
                                     Inventor.Parameter parameter,
                                     EventTimingEnum BeforeOrAfter,
                                     NameValueMap context ,
                                     out HandlingCodeEnum handlingCode)
{
   handlingCode = HandlingCodeEnum.kEventHandled;

   // Worked.
   for ( int i = 1; i <= context.Count; ++i )
   {
      string name = context.Name[i];
      string value = (string)context.Value[name];
   }
}
```

I was surprised by that. Is that expected?

I also noticed that `NameValueMap` inherits `IEnumerable`. I tried using `foreach` to get the items of the `NameValueMap`. However, that only gave me the values of the items. Is there a way to get the names of the items as well?

```
public static void onParameterChange(_Document document,
                                     Inventor.Parameter parameter,
                                     EventTimingEnum BeforeOrAfter,
                                     NameValueMap context ,
                                     out HandlingCodeEnum handlingCode)
{
   handlingCode = HandlingCodeEnum.kEventHandled;

   foreach ( var item in context )
   {
      // How do you get the name?
      string value = item;
   }
}
```

Comment: in the Autodesk Inventor Interop world ALL Enumerables (object types implementing IEnumerable) are 1-based. Not sure, wether this is generally true for COM-Interops per se...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little information on this `NameValueMap` on the internet, so it is hard to tell if there is an existing method to take advantage of.

However, you can always create an extension method to suit your needs:

```
public static class NameValueMapExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, T>> AsEnumerable<T>(this NameValueMap map)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= map.Count; i++)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<object, T>(
                map.Name[i], (T)map.Values[map.Name[i]]);
    }
}

// ...

foreach (var item in context.AsEnumerable())
{
    // item.Key: Name
    // item.Value: ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to C# and will need some time to grok this.

Comment: @Xiaoy312, I have read the Autodesk documentation on NameValueMaps. Your line: `map.Name[i], (T)map.Values[i]);` should be changed to: `map.Name[i], (T)map.Value[map.Name[i]]);` to get it working.
Also I would suggest changing the generic type to `object`, as the values in a `NameValueMap` can be types which don't have a common interface.

Comment: The answer was written based on the provided context, as I dont have access to the autodesk library. Indeed the value indexer should be the name, not `i`. As for, the type of (T), you can always use `AsEnumerable<object>()` which also leave `<OtherTypeOption>`s to be open.

Answer (score 1):

As NameValueMaps do not contain lots of elements, you could also just return a complete Dictionary, instead of yielding KeyValuePair elements. This gives you access to some handy methods, such as `.TryGetValue()`.

```
public static class NameValueMapExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this NameValueMap nameValueMap)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        for (var i = 1; i <= nameValueMap.Count; i++)
            dictionary.Add(nameValueMap.Name[i], nameValueMap.Value[nameValueMap.Name[i]]);
        return dictionary;
     }
}
```